# product-topology on $\mathbb{R} \times X$

Tags: analysis, product-space

Let $(X,||\cdot||_X)$ be a Banach space and $|\cdot|$ the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$.
How to show that $||(t,x)||:=|t|+||x||_X$, $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}  \times X$ induces the product Topology?

Comment: Can you characterize the sets which are open in the topology induced by the norm you’ve defined on $R \times X$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have $(t_n, x_n) \to (t, x)$ iff $t_n\to t$ and $x_n\to x$.